# vuejs - google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, vuejs2, google-tag-manager

I have a `vuejs` project with various pages:

- study.vue
- result.vue

My client want me to add in the `Google Tag Manager` code so that they can use google analytic to track. Where should I add the code in my `.vue` file? Or should I just add it in the `index.html`?

**Update01**

This is what I do so far:

1. I add the `Google Tag Manager` code to the `index.html`.
2. I installed [vue-gtm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-gtm).
3. I have `app.js` and `bootstrap.js`. basically, `bootstrap.js` will have all my other js frameworks added. Like `lodash.js` or 'jquery.js'. I add the sample code from `vue-gtm` into `bootstrap.js`:

   window._ = require('lodash');
   window.moment = require('moment');

   window.Vue = require('vue');

   import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
   Vue.use(VueRouter)

   import VueGtm from 'vue-gtm';
   Vue.use(VueGtm, {
     debug: true
   })
4. In all the `vue` file, I add this code:

   this.$ua.trackView('Sample', 'samplepath');

However I got error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'trackView' of undefined

What seems to be the error?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about the script that you get when you create an account?

There should be two scripts to include in your HTML, one that has comments around it that include `(noscript)` and one that doesn't. Both should probably go in your index.html file (whichever file has the `<head>` and `<body>` tags). The one that *has* the noscript should go *immediately after* the `<body>` tag, the one that *doesn't* have the noscript should go near the top of the `<head>` section.

If you are asking how to *fire* an event, such as when the user interacts with one of those Vue elements, then yes the code for firing the event should go in the Vue component.

UPDATE 1: I looked into it and setup my own Laravel installation to test (since that seems to be what you're using) and tested it. The problem is that `$ua` is part of the [Vue Analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-ua), so if you want to use `$ua` you need to install the `vue-ua` module as well and add that to Vue. I don't know why the documentation for the Tag Manager module shows how to use the Analytics module without making reference to it, maybe you should file an issue on the Tag Manager GitHub to make the documentation more clear!

So in summary, you should replace `$ua` with `$gtm` instead. I tested it and `$gtm` has a `trackView` function so it will probably achieve what you want, but I don't know how to use Google Tag Manager so you'll have to test it out yourself.