# How to Add Google Global Site Tag Script to my Vuejs Application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My client sends me a google analytics script to track traffic on the website(prod). It is a Global Site Tag (gtag.js) and he wants me to add it to the head section of the application. I did my research and could not find a great way to accomplish this, I am thinking of adding this as a vue component to the head of my application. This is what my app.vue looks like this:

```
<template lang="pug">
teleport(to="head")
  meta
.app
  .app__view
    router-view
</template>
```

Should I add the script directly to the base meta component or i should install any additional dependencies? I am confused, can you suggest me a great approach?

I have tried adding the script to the meta component in the head directly like this

```
<template>
  <script async src=“”></script>
<script>
  ...
</script>
</template>
```

But I could not figure out if it is the correct approach, and I did not manage to test it

Comment: It doesn't make sense to append a script specifically to head, your goal is to execute it, something like vue-plugin-load-script. The requirement to add to head can be caused by the necessity to execute a script asap, and you can't achieve this by doing this inside vue app. Don't remember if this is the case for gtag, I assume it's not. There are things such as vue-gtm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vuejs - google tag manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046281/vuejs-google-tag-manager)